# Javascript new Date vs new Date Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

Can someone help me uderstand what the following JavaScript code is doing? Specifically related to the `new Date = new Date`

```
// An array of dates
var eventDates = {};
eventDates[ new Date( '10/04/2017' )] = new Date( '10/04/2017' );
eventDates[ new Date( '10/06/2017' )] = new Date( '10/06/2017' );
eventDates[ new Date( '10/20/2017' )] = new Date( '10/20/2017' );
eventDates[ new Date( '10/26/2017' )] = new Date( '10/26/2017' );
```

It seems like this is the same?

```
// An array of dates
var eventDates = {};
eventDates[ new Date( '10/04/2017' )];
eventDates[ new Date( '10/06/2017' )];
eventDates[ new Date( '10/20/2017' )];
eventDates[ new Date( '10/26/2017' )];
```

Here is the console.log for each array.

[image]

Comment: No, obviously it's not the same? Your second snippet does not do anything with the property references.

Comment: Would it help to write `var d = new Date(…); eventDates[d.toString()] = d;`?

Comment: Well, those aren't even arrays actually

Comment: First snippet you are adding date value to date key in eventDates object. In second you are not assigning anything, so its blank.

Comment: I agree with Bergi, but I think the author has made a mistake in their "Array of Dates"....

Comment: @CodyG. Care to clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example results in an object with keys based on the user's locale's string representation for dates, each containing the same value as a Date object.  This is not particularly useful, in part because the keys will differ depending on the user's locale, and because in order to access the value of one of those keys, you would need to know the date that matches it... which is the value you'd be looking up in the first place.

The second example results in an empty object (because it just references each "key", without assigning a value to it.)

```js
var eventDates = {};
eventDates[new Date('10/04/2017')] = new Date('10/04/2017');
eventDates[new Date('10/06/2017')] = new Date('10/06/2017');
eventDates[new Date('10/20/2017')] = new Date('10/20/2017');
eventDates[new Date('10/26/2017')] = new Date('10/26/2017');
console.log(eventDates);

var eventDates2 = {};
eventDates2[new Date('10/04/2017')];
eventDates2[new Date('10/06/2017')];
eventDates2[new Date('10/20/2017')];
eventDates2[new Date('10/26/2017')];

console.log(eventDates2)
```

It's not clear to me what the author of either of these examples was trying to accomplish.  If you really wanted an array of dates, you would instead do this:

```js
var eventDatesArray = [];
eventDatesArray.push(new Date('10/04/2017'));
eventDatesArray.push(new Date('10/06/2017'));
eventDatesArray.push(new Date('10/20/2017'));
eventDatesArray.push(new Date('10/26/2017'));

console.log(eventDatesArray);
```

Comment: I would assume the first is an attempt to key date objects to their string representation to avoid the cost of reconstruction: i.e. a pointless micro-optimization.

Comment: Could be? But they'd still need to know the date in order to look up the (same) date... something clearly got lost in translation here.

Comment: Agreed. I'm trying and failing to imagine a situation in which you'd actually want to *do* this...

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps they're translating the `Date` object into a string and then want to reconstruct the `Date` object from that string representation. Perhaps they need singleton objects instead of just equivalent objects, so they need to retrieve the same `Date` again…

Comment: That's almost plausible @deceze, and I'd be very curious to see the context where these came from.....

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks for the clearing this up. It makes sense now.  Just as a reference, I used the following post/code when working on this project. http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/highlight-particular-dates-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: OK, yeah I get it: the values on the object keys are irrelevant, you're just using the object as a lookup table for which dates are selected -- reasonable enough. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity!

Answer (score 1):

It'not the same.
In the first array you are setting the `new Date` object to be the key and the value of the array.

In the second you are setting just the key.

example:
Lets say you have an array , `array = {};`

If you wanna set the key of the array you do it like this.

```
array['key1'] = someValue1;
array['key2'] = someValue2;
array['key3'] = someValue3;
```

And then you can get these values with each key.

```
var variable1 = array['key1'];
```

Now if you console.log this `variable1` you get `someValue1`

```js
let array1 = {};

array1['key1'] = 1;
array1['key2'] = 2;
array1['key2'] = 3;

let array2 = {};

array2['key1'];
array2['key2'];
array2['key2'];

console.log('First Array',array1['key1']);
console.log('First Array',array2['key1']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Daniel Beck's correct answer, here is a more straightforward version of the first example using today's date:

```
let string2DateHash = {
  // date pre-stringified
  "Wed Nov 01 2017 08:22:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)": new Date()
};
```

This is equivalent to

```
let string2DateHash = {
  // new ES 6 short-hand property, calls .toString
  [new Date()]: new Date()
};
```

Which is equivalent to your original

```
// also calls .toString behind the scenes
var string2DateHash = {};
string2DateHash[new Date()] = new Date();
```